# Jenkins - download from an Artifactory speedup

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, artifactory

We are using jenkins pipeline job to download a folder from Artifactory. Is there a way to speed it up? To pass somehow number of `nproc` that can be used? Something like in a jfrog cli?
**jfrog cli:**

```
jfrog rt dl --threads=`nproc`....
```

How can we pass the same in Jenkins declarative pipeline job?
In Jfrog [documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Working+With+Pipeline+Jobs+in+Jenkins) - no mentioning for that :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use --limit option with --sort-order. It will download the latest artifactory.

For e.g.
jfrog rt dl  "my-local-repo/all-my-frogs/" --sort-by=created --sort-order=desc --limit=1

Comment: thanks, but I would like to use jenkins pipeline declarative and NOT jfrog cli.